# How to draw a pixel through video memory using C?

Tags: c, pixel, vga

*Problem:*

I have followed the tutorial at https://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode and encountered a problem drawing a pixel using the given function.

*What i've done:*

1. Changed video mode using a **BIOS** interrupt in the bootloader to 113h(VBE) from the http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/videomodes.txt table;

2. Accesed the video memory using the function given

```c
/* only valid for 800x600x32bpp */
static void putpixel(unsigned char* screen, int x,int y, int color) {
    unsigned where = x*4 + y*3200;
    screen[where] = color & 255;              // BLUE
    screen[where + 1] = (color >> 8) & 255;   // GREEN
    screen[where + 2] = (color >> 16) & 255;  // RED
}
```

which was taken from the article, with video memory in a macro

```c
#define VGA 0xA0000
```

3. And attempted to call it as follows

```c
putpixel(VGA, 10, 10, 3);
```

4. Ensured that was not due to the tinyness of the pixel by using a loop to try to display more of them

*Results:*

Expected: A pixel on the screen in QEMU

Actual: Nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pixel is nearly black, it has colour <0, 0, 3>. You could try calling this as

```
putpixel(VGA, 10, 10, 0x00FFFFFF);
```

That would put a nice white pixel on the screen.

Comment: Wow! It did work, seems my question was really silly! Thanks a lot, i will be able to mark the answer in 4 minutes